# Restoring taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Unfortunately, my taskbar has been thrown off balance, possibly as a result of my baby randomly tapping buttons of the keyboard. Please see the attached pictures. Somehow all my apps have spread over multiple rows of the taskbar.

I have extensively looked into the settings and also on the internet for similar issues but have not found a way to restore this unbelievably messy taskbar to its original one-line shape. Could I please ask for some help?

Thank you in advance.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Somehow all my apps have spread over multiple rows of the taskbar

You need to resize it:

> You can also resize the taskbar to get a little additional space. This can be particularly handy if you moved it to the right or left edge of your screen, but it’s also good if you just want space for loads of icons. Right-click the taskbar and turn off the “Lock the taskbar” option. Then place your mouse at the top edge of the taskbar and drag to resize it just like you would with a window. You can increase the size of the taskbar up to about half your screen size.

Source [How to Customize the Taskbar in Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/225568/how-to-configure-and-customize-the-taskbar-in-windows-10/)

In your case drag down to make it smaller.